# SQL query confusion for startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, select-query

I have a table(e.g. *tableA*) like this:

```
| Name  | Startdate  |  Enddate   |
|---------------------------------|
|  a    | 2012-07-01 | 2013-06-30 |
|  b    | 2011-05-01 | 2012-04-30 |
|  c    | 2010-01-01 | 2013-12-31 |
|  d    | 2013-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
|  e    | 2011-07-01 | 2012-06-30 |
```

I want to get a *name* from the table who is active between `2012-05-01` and `2012-10-31`. From above table the result should be ***a,c and e***.

What I have done is as following:

```
SELECT Name FROM tableA WHERE startdate<='2012-05-01' AND enddate>='2012-10-31'
```

But I am not getting the correct result.

Comment: the right should be: startdate>='2012-05-01' AND enddate<='2012-10-31'

Comment: Do you want the results that are valid for the entire period?

Comment: @RobB Yes. I want the results that are valid for the given period(between 2012-05-01 and 2012-10-31)

Comment: Have not used ms-sql for a while, but in oracle you will need to convert string '2012-05-01' to date before you could compare the dates, otherwise you will end up comparing strings like 'a'<'b'.

Comment: @hims056 what's the datatype of `startdate` and `enddate`?

Comment: You should use the proper, language-independent format for specifying just dates against `DATETIME` - and that format is `yyyyMMdd` - so try: `...WHERE startdate <= '20120501' AND enddate >= '20121031'`. The format with the dashes is **not safe** and can be misinterpreted depending on the language setting of your SQL Server. Plus your comparison operators should be reversed, too - it should be greater or equal to `20120501` and smaller or equal to `20121031` - right?

Comment: @hims056 and what output you are getting?

Comment: Since no-one's mentioned it in any of their answers - it's best to avoid specifying dates (without times) as `YYYY-MM-DD` - they can be ambiguous to SQL Server. Better to just use `YYYYMMDD` with no separator characters.

Comment: @marc_s and @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right I will use `yyyyMMDD`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  Name char(1),
  Startdate datetime,
  Enddate datetime
)

insert into @T values
('a',     '20120701',  '20130630'), 
('b',     '20110501',  '20120430'), 
('c',     '20100101',  '20131231'), 
('d',     '20130101',  '20141231'), 
('e',     '20110701',  '20120630')

declare @StartDate datetime = '20120501'
declare @EndDate datetime = '20121031'

select Name
from @T 
where Startdate < @EndDate and
      Enddate > @StartDate
```

Comment: I got the result what I wanted. [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d403/1)

Comment: New fiddle with date format `yyyyMMdd` is updated [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7619d/1)

Comment: I want to vote this ++++. Seemingly simple, but when you've been staring at this sort of problem for a while, you don't quite see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to find any results that occurred during the period then utilize [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

```
SELECT Name FROM tableA WHERE startdate BETWEEN '2012-05-01' and '2012-10-31'
```

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than
>   or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to
>   the value of end_expression.
>
> NOT BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is less than
>   the value of begin_expression or greater than the value of
>   end_expression.

Comment: If I use `startdate BETWEEN '2012-05-01' and '2012-10-31'` then I will not get **a** as it is active in that period.

Comment: According to your question `a` has an enddate of '2013-06-30'.  The BETWEEN expression will only return a match if both the startdate and enddate are within (between) the specified dates.

Answer (score 0):

Placement of comparison operator were creating problem check this

```
SELECT Name FROM tableA WHERE startdate>='2012-05-01' AND enddate<='2012-10-31'
```

Comment: You should try this query against the data. It does not return any rows at all.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson It wont because table does not contain any record in the given date range. As he has asked in question record active between " active between '2012-05-01' and '2012-10-31'" means start date of the record should be greater then or equal to 2012-05-01 but if question is to have all the records in which this date range comes then your query is right. May be i have interpreted it wrong!!!

Comment: SELECT Name FROM table1 WHERE startdate between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-31' or enddate between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-31'

Comment: OP wants overlapping date ranges. Not entirely within the interval.

Comment: @Deepesh See the question again. I wanted the result where `'2012-05-01'` and `'2012-10-31'` exist between _startdate_ and _enddate_